# React Native, cart item values are not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a cart component for my shopping app but I'm facing a problem that when I update the quantity of product it's updating total price but not item price(image in the end), my code is below

reducer.js

```
if (action.type === ADD_TO_CART) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
    let existed_item = state.addedItems.find((item) => action.id === item.id);
    if (existed_item) {
      addedItem.quantity += 1;
      return {
        ...state.jeans,
        total: state.total + addedItem.price,
      };
    } else {
      addedItem.quantity = 1;
      let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price;

      return {
        ...state,
        addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
        total: newTotal,
      };
    }
  }
  //INSIDE CART COMPONENT
  if (action.type === ADD_QUANTITY) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
    addedItem.quantity += 1;
    let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price;
    return {
      ...state,
      total: newTotal,
    };
  }
  if (action.type === SUB_QUANTITY) {
    let addedItem = state.jeans.find((item) => item.id === action.id);
    //if the qt == 0 then it should be removed
    if (addedItem.quantity === 1) {
      let new_items = state.addedItems.filter((item) => item.id !== action.id);
      let newTotal = state.total - addedItem.price;
      return {
        ...state,
        addedItems: new_items,
        total: newTotal,
      };
    } else {
      addedItem.quantity -= 1;
      let newTotal = state.total - addedItem.price;
      return {
        ...state,
        total: newTotal,
      };
    }
```

that's my reducer where I added function to update quantity,

cart.js

```
Footer = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.totalContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.textTotal}>Total:</Text>
        <Text style={styles.total}>Rs {this.props.total}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    let addedItems =
      this.props.items && this.props.items.length ? (
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.items}
          key={(items) => items.id.toString()}
          numColumns={2}
          ListFooterComponent={this.Footer}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.cartContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="delete-circle-outline"
                  size={28}
                  onPress={() => this.props.removeItem(item.id)}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
              <View style={{ width: 150 }}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.subTitle} numberOfLines={1}>
                  {item.subTitle}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <Text style={styles.quantity} numberOfLines={2}>
                {item.quantity}
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.price}>Rs {item.price}</Text>
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  style={styles.iconUp}
                  size={20}
                  name="plus-circle-outline"
                  onPress={() => this.props.addQuantity(item.id)}
                />
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                style={styles.iconDown}
                size={20}
                name="minus-circle-outline"
                onPress={() => this.props.subtractQuantity(item.id)}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        />
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.emptyContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.empty}>There is Nothing in your Cart</Text>
        </View>
      );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.order}>
          <Text style={styles.orderText}>You Orders:</Text>
        </View>
        <View>{addedItems}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.clothes.addedItems,
    total: state.clothes.total,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    removeItem: (id) => dispatch(removeItem(id)),
    addQuantity: (id) => dispatch(addQuantity(id)),
    subtractQuantity: (id) => dispatch(subtractQuantity(id)),
  };
};
```

It's my cart code, here I'm facing another problem that my footer function is displaying and flat List not working properly if I add more products Flat list will only show 3 products and other products will we added above them.

[image]

will someone please help me and tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating the price anywhere

you can do like below

```
<Text style={styles.price}>Rs {item.price*item.quantity}</Text>
```

Or if you want the values to be in the redux state consider updating the value in the reducer level.

Comment: how can I update value in redux state, I tried to update value in redux state but when I decrement it the total value not decrement properly

Comment: You will have to handle it in both scenarios

Comment: `<Text style={styles.price}>Rs {item.price*item.quantity}</Text>` it worked , I also mentioned another problem did you read it?

Comment: what do you mean by 'above them' ?

Comment: not that one footer is displaying in flat list, I already solved above problem I accidentally mention the number of columns and i'm getting that error in flat list `Failed child context type: Invalid child context 'virtualizedCell.cellKey' of type `number` supplied to 'CellRenderer', expected 'string'`

Comment: ah that warning try keyExtractor = { (item, index) => item.id.toString() } instead of the key you have used

Comment: oh that's silly mistake didn't notice that, what about footer I'm sure I gave value correctly, I used it in home page too it worked there :/

Comment: So your footer is going below the viewing area is it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223085/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-kanwarjeet-singh).